# How do I set text color to a particular String in a TextArea?

Tags: java, css, javafx, textcolor

I am developing a client for a web server application. The client has a TextArea that is displaying text both from the web server and from the client. I want the input to the client to have a particular color (in CSS) to distinguish it. The input is stored in the String `userAnswer`. Is it possible to create an ID that is connected with the String or any other way to do this?

```
Out.appendText(userAnswer + "\n");
```

Comment: JTextArea does not support different color for different text. Also, JTextArea does not support HTML ( or CSS). You may consider using JEditorPane or JTextPane.

Comment: JTextArea is a Swing property and not JavaFX.

Comment: Yea, I was talking about Swing. Didn't see your javafx tagging there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `TextArea` doesn't have that functionality (at least as of JavaFX 8). There is a [GitHub](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX) project called RichTextFX which might have what you are looking for, however. It has the ability to style ranges of text with different CSS stylings.